# Difference between 'LIKE' and 'IN' in meta queries

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, mysql, meta-query

You can use a variety of different comparison operators in meta queries, among which are `'LIKE'`, `'NOT LIKE'`, `'IN'`, and `'NOT IN'`.

What is the difference in use between `LIKE` and `IN`?

Here's the relevant section of the [WP Query Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters):

> #### meta_query (*array*) - Custom field
>   parameters (3.1)
>
> - **key** (*string*) - Custom field key.
> - **value**
>     (*string*|*array*) - Custom field value (*Note*: Array
>     support is limited to a compare value of 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or
>     'NOT BETWEEN')
> - **compare** (*string*) -
>     Operator to test. Possible values are '=', '!=', '>', '>=',
>     '<', '<=', 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT
>     BETWEEN'. Default value is '='.
> - **type**
>     (*string*) - Custom field type. Possible values are 'NUMERIC',
>     'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME',
>     'UNSIGNED'. Default value is 'CHAR'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta queries are essentially wrapper for ease of setup, but end results is part of SQL query to run on MySQL database.

These operators are those of MySQL, see in documentation:

- [`LIKE` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) (performs pattern matching)
- [`IN()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) (checks if value is in set)

Comment: So `IN` would accept an array?

Comment: @supertrue from quick look at code it should and `IN` seems to be even automatically used instead of `=` in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly used two operates in metaa queries 1. like 2. in 
 1 - [`LIKE`  (performs pattern matching) or not ]
2  - [`IN()`  (checks if value is in set or not ]

```
array(
    'key' => 'practice_area',
    'value' => '"'.$post->ID.'"',
    'compare' => 'LIKE',
)
```